# SASS listen warning: missing rb-fevent

Tags: ruby, sass

I've just started using SASS, and the listener seems to work fairly well although I noticed a problem:
    [Listen warning]:
    Missing dependency 'rb-fsevent' (version '~> 0.9')!

I tried to install rb-fsevent but it still isn't working.

```
rata:css murray$ gem install rb-fsevent
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.9.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.9.4
Parsing documentation for rb-fsevent-0.9.4
Installing ri documentation for rb-fsevent-0.9.4
1 gem installed
rata:css murray$  sass --style compressed --watch scss:.
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
[Listen warning]:
  Missing dependency 'rb-fsevent' (version '~> 0.9')!
  Please run the following to satisfy the dependency:
    gem install --version '~> 0.9' rb-fsevent

  For a better performance, it's recommended that you satisfy the missing dependency.
  Listen will be polling changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback.
```

I then read a few other StackOverflow problems but it just kept getting worse.  Is there a simple fix?  If not I will live with the poor performance.

I'm on OSX 10.9.2
Sass 3.2.11 (Media Mark)
I know nothing about Ruby or it's configuration - so if you are explaining anything please be clear.